# Different substitutions in First order logic?

Tags: logic, substitution

In First order logic the substitution F{x1 / s1}{x2 / s2} ...{xn / sn} can be different from F{x1 / s1, x2 / s2, ... xn / sn}. How these substitutions can be different? Can someone give me example of such substitution?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

(I use the convention that $[\tau/x]$ means "put $\tau$ in place of $x$" or "$\tau$ substituted for $x$.")

Here's a simple example:

$$y[x/y][y/x] = y, \qquad y[x/y,y/x] = x$$

Comment: @BrianO, for what its worth, I actually prefer to write $[\tau/x]\varphi$ as opposed to $\varphi[\tau/x].$ Then we can treat substitution as a homomorphism, e.g. $$[\tau/x](\varphi \wedge \psi) = [\tau/x] \varphi \wedge [\tau/x] \psi$$ This seems not to be very widespread, though.

Comment: Yep me too: it seems more intuitive that the thing being substituted for should be nearer the formula, and that the thing being substituted should "lean against it" as it to replace it in the formula.  I guess the $[\tau/x]$ on the right convention has always struck me as backwards, obtuse. I just searched on "first order logic substitution term variable" and many examples; amusingly, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_%28logic%29) and newer authors throw up their hands and use the unambiguous "{ x1 ↦ t1, ..., xk ↦ tk }".

Comment: @BrianO, arrows are always good :)